# D3. How to update data when recall function (without button)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bubble chart with forceCollide. I'm trying update data and change circles's radius when recall function (without button)
This code work correctly. But when I recal function with new data, it redraw over my old circles.

```
function DrawBubbleChart(data) {
        var svg = d3.select("svg")
            ...
        var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")
            ...
        var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
            .force("x", ...)
            .force("y", ...)
            .force("collide", ...);

        simulation.nodes(data)
            .on("tick", ...);   

        d3.select("#btn").on("click", () => {
            node.transition().duration(1000).attr("r", d => d.r);
            simulation.nodes(data);
            simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
        })
    }
```

What I'm trying:

```
 function DrawBubbleChart(data) {

    if(empty){
            var svg = d3.select("svg")
                ...
            var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")
                ...
            var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
                .force("x", ...)
                .force("y", ...)
                .force("collide", ...);

            simulation.nodes(data)
                .on("tick", ...);   
    } else {
            //d3.select("#btn").on("click", () => {
                node.transition().duration(1000).attr("r", d => d.r);
                simulation.nodes(data);
                simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
            })
        }
```

or something similar. What is the best way(solution) for this?

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Edited @GerardoFurtado

Comment: Where is `empty` defined?  What's it's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea creating a single function to draw **and** update your bubble chart, for a simple reason: when updating the chart, you have to create a function that has access to the previous position and sizes of the bubbles. Those are the properties assigned by the simulation:

- index - the node’s zero-based index into nodes
- x - the node’s current x-position
- y - the node’s current y-position
- vx - the node’s current x-velocity
- vy - the node’s current y-velocity

And, in your case, an additional one, `r`. It's possible, but it's complicated.

My advice is: create a function for drawing the bubbles for the first time and, then, inside that function, create another function that deals with the new data. That way, the transition is smooth.

For instance, in the below demo, I'm checking the data of the bubbles and changing the `r` property. You can create a similar function, that updates the data bound to the bubbles, maintaining their positions.

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var colour = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var data = d3.range(30).map(d => ({
    r: 6
}));

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(data)
    .force("x", d3.forceX(150).strength(0.05))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(75).strength(0.05))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
        return d.r + 1;
    }));

var node = svg.selectAll(".circles")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", d => d.r)
    .attr("fill", (d, i) => colour(i));

setInterval(()=>{
    d3.selectAll("circle").data().forEach(d => d.r = Math.random()*15);
  node.transition().duration(400).attr("r", d => d.r);
    simulation.nodes(data);
    simulation.alpha(0.8).restart();
}, 3000);

simulation.nodes(data)
    .on("tick", d => {
        node.attr("cx", d => d.x).attr("cy", d => d.y);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```